# hook_entity_view_alter doesn't seem to be working

Tags: entities, users

I'm trying to alter a Registration entity (created by the Entity Registration module) and am using hook_entity_view_alter. I can see that my code is being called when the page loads, but it doesn't change the output at all.

Here's my code:

```
function modulename_entity_view_alter(&$build, $type) {

    if($type == 'registration') {
        $edit_path = url("registration/{$build['#entity']->registration_id}/edit", array('options'=>array('absolute'=>TRUE)));
        $delete_path = url("registration/{$build['#entity']->registration_id}/delete", array('options'=>array('absolute'=>TRUE)));

        $markup = "<span class='registration-edit-link'>";
        $markup .= "<a href='$edit_path'>Edit your registration</a>";
        $markup .= '</span>';

        $markup .= "<span class='registration-delete-link'>";
        $markup .= "<a href='$delete_path'>Cancel your registration</a>";
        $markup .= '</span>';

        $build['links'] = array(
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => $markup,
            //'#weight' => 1000,
        );

    }
}
```

Edit: I've changed to trying to use hook_entity_view but am having the same problem. Trying to add something to $entity->content doesn't result in anything new being output on the page.

Comment: I'd try doing this in hook_preprocess_entity(). Better yet, use hook_field_extra_fields() and configure your new fields from the display UI.

Comment: Are you using Display Suite?

Comment: Yes, but it hasn't been configured for the Registration Entity.

Comment: Oops, looks like DS was in use on the Registration Entity. Sneaky front end devs, enabling things behind my back.